# How to build selector with $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Hello i using this selector

```
var id = $(".tg_li-HeaderMenu >div").tabindex();
```

this select me all elements with this class and i need only that element that i clicked on that it

How to make selector like this

```
var id = $((this)>div).tabindex();
```

Or how to select the div child

This my html i need to get tabindex of element that i clicked on

```
  <li id="listMenu" class="tg_li-HeaderMenu">
DASHBOARD
<div class="TopMenuActive" tabindex=" 1"></div>
</li>
<li id="listMenu" class="tg_li-HeaderMenu">
ORDERS
<div class="TopMenuActive" tabindex=" 2"></div>
</li>
<li id="listMenu" class="tg_li-HeaderMenu SelectedMenu">
<li id="listMenu" class="tg_li-HeaderMenu">
```

This my Javascript

```
$(".tg_li-HeaderMenu").click(function () {
    var id = $(".tg_li-HeaderMenu >div");
    console.log("id-->", id[0].tabindex());

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
var id = $('>div', this).tabindex();
```

or

```
var id = $(this).children('div').tabindex();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can to use [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/), also to get the `tabindex` attribute value you need to use [.att()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) as shown below

```
$(".tg_li-HeaderMenu").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).children("div");
    console.log("id-->", id.attr('tabindex'));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A6XTt/)